# Are there any compound lists searchable by elemental content?

Tags: organic-chemistry

As I say in the question, I am looking for lists of compounds that I can search based on elemental content. Essentially, I want to find candidate compounds for boron doping liquid scintillator, we have a few likely candidates already but we want to see the available chemical space and see if there are better/cheaper candidates. I want to avoid high electron densities, so essentially I want to find compounds that only have boron, carbon, and hydrogen. I will filter later for hazard/reactivity/flammability.

Does such a list / service exist? If not, is there a general list of compounds with their formulas that I could then parse with a python script or something?

Comment: Check out [Matweb](http://www.matweb.com/). It's free and might be of use to you.

Comment: A bit of searching shows little of use there sadly, mostly they list things like boron nitride, boron carbide, and alloys with boron in them which would not dissolve well at all. Thanks though, and it could be quite useful for other purposes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, followed by asking reddit, I got a few good suggestions.
[ChemSpider's](http://www.chemspider.com/) advanced search method allows you to, among other things, search for elements containing specific elements and lacking other elements.

Also, for large lists of compounds I can use python tools to extract the tables from the [CRC Handbook](http://www.hbcpnetbase.com/) pdfs and then, search that data.